# Margin-bottom and margin-top doesn't work

Tags: html, css

Here is the source:

```
<div style="border:1px solid red; margin-bottom:10px">test block1,</div>;    
<div style="border:1px solid red; margin-top:10px">test block2</div>;
```

It always has `10px` between block1 and block2...

I'm not sure what is wrong.  Please don't say 'use `padding`' and 'change `20px`'

I have to use `margin-bottom`, `margin-top` and only `10px`.

Comment: as i think it happen because if    we dont use the float and width or clear

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's called **collapsing margin**

as per w3c

> In CSS, the adjoining margins of two or more boxes (which might or
>   might not be siblings) can combine to form a single margin. Margins
>   that combine this way are said to collapse, and the resulting combined
>   margin is called a collapsed margin.

Read this http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/collapsingmargins

Answer (score 1):

Use `float: left;` and maybe also `clear: both;` for both divs and it will work for sure ;)